# Write the function

Tags: calculus

Now, I realise that there are infinite possible functions for such a curve because of varying slopes at different values of x. So, I'm actually looking for the family of curves that can best describe something like this.
[image]

Comment: Looks like $a\arctan(|x|)$

Comment: Or $a\frac{|x|}{|x|+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function of the form $f(x)=g(|x|)$ where $g$ is an increasing concave function with $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=a$ will work.

Letting, $g(x)=a[1-h(x)]$ we need $h$ convex with $h(0)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=0$.

For example, you could take $h(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$, so that 
$$f(x)=a-\frac{a}{1+|x|}.$$

Comment: Oh great. Can you please tell how that particular function CLICKED to you rather than any other

Comment: What was your thought process behind the same ?

Comment: They are both the same.

Comment: Yeah,  got it

Comment: Shouldn't there be |x| in the function?

Comment: There shouldn't be any discontinuity at x=-1

Comment: Yes, I put the absolute value symbol in the wrong place. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

QUESTION.- Do you want your curves necessarily be all concave? If not, you have a nice example to add to the concave ones with the Witch of Agnesi, whose equation is     $y=\frac{8a^3}{x^2+4a^2}$  where        $a$ is the radius of the circle that generates the curve (so you have infinitely many examples).

In the figure you have (with $ a = 300$) a "witch" and a good exercise for you would be to find the right equation to figure reflected down the given (i.e. changing the given equation to the red coordinates).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Btw there was supposed to be non-differentiability at x=0

Comment: But thanks anyway for telling me about this curve which I didn't know of earlier

Comment: @user115962: If you search for non-differentiability at $x=0$ then the "witchs" are not solutions.

Comment: Then just replace x^2 with |x|.......and there you have your non-differentiability